# Reading and storing integers in a file

Tags: c++, io, fstream

I have a file.txt such as  :

```
15 25 32 // exactly 3 integers in the first line. 
string1
string2
string3
*
*
*
*
```

What I want to do is, reading 15,25,32 and store them into lets say int a,b,c;

Is there anyone to help me  ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `std::ifstream` to read file content:

```
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream infile("filename.txt");
```

Then you can read the line with the numbers using `std::getline()`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
std::string line;
std::getline(infile, line);
```

Then, you can use a `std::istringstream` to parse the integers stored in that line:

```
std::istringstream iss(line);
int a;
int b;
int c;

iss >> a >> b >> c;
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note that @KerrekSB's answer also shows error detection.

Comment: @Mr.C64: Yeah, it would arguably be undefined behaviour to access `a`, `b` or `c` if the extraction were to fail.

Answer (score 2):

The standard idiom uses iostreams:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");

std::string first_line;

if (!infile || !std::getline(first_line, infile)) { /* bad file, die */ }

std::istringstream iss(first_line);
int a, b, c;

if (!(iss >> a >> b >> c >> std::ws) || iss.get() != EOF)
{ 
    // bad first line, die
}

// use a, b, c
```